# Python - how to save the save the file after replace string

Tags: python, excel, file, save

I got the question right here that I try to save the excel file after I replace the string in it, everything is ok, but it seems not write back into excel file. Can anyone explain this to me? thank you very much!

```
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook('C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\test.csv')
wb = copy(rb)
sheet = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0, 0)

first_row_list = sheet.row_values(0)
name_index = first_row_list.index('Name') 
print(name_index)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    target_column = sheet.cell_value(i, name_index)
    print(i)
    target_column.replace("a", "b")
    print(target_column.replace("a", "b"))
wb.save('C:\\Users\\Eric\\Desktop\\test.csv'`
```

Comment: print(target_column.replace("a", "b"))
works well and it can print the replacing stuff out, but it seems cannot store in excel.Any help at this moment is much appreciate!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `replace()` method returns the replaced string but not update the string passed to it.

Simply replace:

```
target_column.replace("a", "b")
```

with:

```
target_column = target_column.replace("a", "b")
```

Comment: got it, thank you very much for the help and I fixed it!